# Kivy- Multiple Animations and placement

Tags: python, kivy

can anyone help me with with animation placement and the how to add multiple of animations?  So i got the animation of the circle that i need  and it work just fine, but not only i need to add another one and smaller. But i also need to place them in specific place as shown on the PS sketch (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmKMS.png). So if anyone could help me please, ill be really thankful :)

```
That teh code!
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

Builder.load_string('''                               
<Loading>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin:  1150, 480 
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix


    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, 1, .1, .9
        Line:
            width: 2.
            circle:
                (self.center_x, self.center_y, min(1150, 480)
                / 2, 90, 180, 10)
<Loading2>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin:  1150.480
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix


    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, 1, .1, .9
        Line:
            width: 2.
            circle:
                (self.center_x, self.center_y, min(1150, 480)
                / 4, 90, 180, 10)`enter code here`
''')

class Loading(FloatLayout):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        anim = Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim += Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(self)


     def on_angle(self, item, angle):
        if angle == 360:
            item.angle = 0
class Loading2(FloatLayout):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        anim = Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim += Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(self)

def on_angle(self, item, angle):
        if angle == 360:
            item.angle = 0

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Loading()
        return Loading2()

TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems with your code:

1. The `build()` method (or any method) can only execute one `return`, so your second `return` is ignored.
2. You have too many arguments to your `circle`.
3. The `origin` of your `Rotate` is likely off the screen. I think you want to rotate about the circle center.
4. The `super()` in `Loading2` references `Loading` instead of `Loading2`.
5. There are a couple indentation errors (probably just from copy/paste of code).

So here is a modified version of your code that does most of what you want:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

kv = '''
FloatLayout:
    Loading:
        size_hint: 0.3, 1
    Loading2:
        size_hint: 0.7, 1
        pos_hint: {'right':1}                               
<Loading>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin:  root.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix


    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, 1, .1, .9
        Line:
            width: 2.
            circle:
                (root.center_x, root.center_y, 100, 90, 180, 10)
<Loading2>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin:  root.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix


    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, 1, .1, .9
        Line:
            width: 2.
            circle:
                (root.center_x, root.center_y, 200, 90, 180, 10)
'''


class Loading(FloatLayout):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        anim = Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim += Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(self)


    def on_angle(self, item, angle):
        if angle == 360:
            item.angle = 0


class Loading2(FloatLayout):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        anim = Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim += Animation(angle = 360, duration=2)
        anim.repeat = True
        anim.start(self)

    def on_angle(self, item, angle):
            if angle == 360:
                item.angle = 0


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

TestApp().run()
```

I have added a root `FloatLayout` to your `kv`, so that both the `Loading` and `Loading2` classes are in your GUI.

Comment: thank you so much! and i got one last question? so in order to change place the 'loading' i just have to change last set of coordinate in   '(root.center_x, root.center_y, 200, 90, 180, 10)' is that right ?

Comment: The code `root.center_x, root.center_y` just sets the center of the circle to the center of the `root` (which is the `Loading` instance in this case. So, if you change `root.center_x, root.center_y` to something else, it will just move the circle.